# Solve the differential equation: $(y^2-xy)dx+x^2dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$(y^2-xy)dx+x^2dy=0$$

Need step by step answer.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: divide through by $x^{2}$ and look at it.

Comment: I'm new to this differentiation so I don't really know how to go about it. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Try to substitute $v=\frac{y}{x}$ and try to solve

Comment: @Charlie Robson:
According to http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/701815/revisions, you had completely changed to this question. This is not appropriate for SEs. Please ask the separate question for the new question.

Answer (score 1):

With some manipulation, we have
$$(y^2 - xy)dx + x^2dy = 0$$
$$(xy - y^2)dx = x^2dy$$
$$\begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{xy - y^2}{x^2}\\
&= \frac{y}{x} - \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2\end{align}$$

Now, let $v = \frac{y}{x} \implies y = vx \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = v + x\frac{dv}{dx}$ (product rule). Then,
$$v + x\frac{dv}{dx} = v - v^2$$
$$x\frac{dv}{dx} = -v^2$$
$$\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{dv}{dx} = -\frac{1}{x}$$
Integrating both sides W.R.T $x$,
$$\int\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{dv}{dx}\cdot dx = \int\frac{-1}{x}dx$$
$$\int\frac{1}{v^2}dv = \int\frac{-1}{x}dx$$
$$-v^{-1} = -\ln{|x|} - C$$
where $C$ is the constant of integration. Then,
$$v^{-1} = \ln{|x|} + C$$
$$v = \frac{1}{\ln{|x|} + C}$$
But $v = \frac{y}{x}$, so
$$\frac{y}{x} = \frac{1}{\ln{|x|} + C}$$
$$y = \frac{x}{\ln{|x|} + C}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help so far
Before the integration, is it supposed to be just '-1/x' or '-(1/x)x'? Thank you

Comment: My mistake, it should be just a -1/x. Ive edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do the proper formatting, but...
The next line would be:
-v^-1=1?

Comment: Or am I completely wrong, I'm having a mind block

Comment: Of course! God I am not doing well today, thanks again!

Comment: Almost: the integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\ln{|x|}$. I have to go to bed now, so i've edited my answer to show all the steps.

Comment: Glad I could help! Do remember to mark any of the answers posted to your questions if you find they are useful and sufficient, by click the tick beside it.